# Unity works fine in editor but the scripts aren't starting in build

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I've made my first unity project and everything works fine in the editor. There are multiple c# scripts, and they all worked. However, when I made a Windows build, the scripts didn't start and only the objects were shown. The game just stands there, and you need to close it with Task Manager. Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: Compile it with debug options and console. This should let you see any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! I tried to run it with the `Update` method, and this had many more frames in the editor than in the build. However, I found the `FixedUpdate` Method that always runs the same frames. With that, I found out I needed much more Force added to the object.

Answer (score 0):

It happens a lot to me and I still don't know  what causes that. There are some cases where rebuilding the project helps, so try rebuilding the project

Comment: Thanks for your tip, but this didn't work.

Comment: "The definition of insanity is doing the same thing over and over and expecting different results." - Albert Einstein

Comment: @derHugo You know, coding is mostly a kind of insanity.

Comment: @GoldenretriverYT it was Update instead of fixed update